# Using a variable from one function in an other - think im missing something

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is most probably simple but im struggling a little is it possible to do something like the below becasue its not alerting in the 2nd function.

```
function func1() {
  var test = 5;
  var testAgain = 8;
}


function func3() {
  func1();
  alert(test);
}
```

edit:

Thank you all for your comments, however i cant seem to get it to work.

i below is the code i am trying to get this to work in

it does not seem to want to pass the vars from setImageReelWidth, and just alerts 0 when it gets to rotate = function () or $(".paging a").click(function (). so i click and it alerts 4 (which is correct) and then when it runs it twice again i just get 0

```
var divWidth = 0;
var slideTotal = 0;
var divReelWidth = 0;


function setImageReelWidth() {
    var divWidth = $(".window").width();
    var slideTotal = $(".slide").size();
    var divReelWidth = divWidth * slideTotal;
    alert(slideTotal);
    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({ 'width': divReelWidth });
}





$(document).ready(function () {
    ////////////////////////////  INITAL SET UP  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
    //var divWidth = $(".window").width();
    //var slideTotal = $(".slide").size();
    //var divReelWidth = divWidth * slideTotal;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    //$(".image_reel").css({ 'width': divReelWidth });

    //set the initial not active state
    $('#prev').attr("class", "not_active");

    ////////////////////////////  SLIDER  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function () {
        setImageReelWidth();
        alert(slideTotal);
        var triggerID = $slideNumber - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * divWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide
        //sets the active on the next and prev
        if ($slideNumber == 1) {
            $('#prev').attr("class", "not_active")
            $('#next').attr("class", "active")
        }
        else if ($slideNumber == slideTotal) {
            $('#next').attr("class", "not_active");
            $('#prev').attr("class", "active");
        }
        else {
            $('#prev').attr("class", "active")
            $('#next').attr("class", "active")
        };
        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500);
    };

    ////////////////////////////  SLIDER CALLS  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    //click on numbers
    $(".paging a").click(function () {
        setImageReelWidth();
        alert(slideTotal);
        setImageReelWidth();
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        $slideNumber = $active.attr("rel");
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to write `alert(test);` not `alert('test');`, since alert with the String 'test' does not use your variable. However, this does solve your problem, see my answer below.

Comment: When you use the `var` keyword in the functions, it creates a new local variable instead of using the global variables. Just remove the `var` words from inside the function.

Comment: perfect thats what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the variable with global scope.

```
var test = 0;

function func1() {
    test = 5;
}


function func3() {
    func1();
    alert(test);
}
```

Further reading on [variable scope in javascript](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html)

Answer (score 6):

Making the variable available to both methos, by defining it globally, like [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174390/60518), is fine.

Another solution would be to **return it from the first function** and use it in the second like this:

```
function func1() {
  var test = 5;
  return test;
}


function func3() {
  var x = func1();
  alert(x);
}
```

**EDIT**
Another way to do it, is writing a factory function to create func3:

```
var func3 = (function(){

  var test;

  function func1() {
      test = 5;
  }

  return function() {
      func1();
      alert(test);
  }


})();
```

What happens here is the following:
I created a function, that gets executed right away:

```
(function(){      
    // ...        
})();
```

In there, I have the variable `test` and another function called `func1` and I **return a function** that gets bound to the variable `func3`. `func3` has now access to the var `test` as well as `func1` **but nothing outside that factory** function I wrote **can access them**.

Check out the fiddle I created: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/NF7Sh/).

Stuff like this is a little hard to understand at first, but it's really the power of JavaScript (IMHO).

Comment: +1 This is a much better method than my answer of a global variable.

Comment: Well, the question is what sluap trying to achieve. We need to see the bigger picture to decide what fits here. You shouldn't have remove you answer. Besides, there are ways to have a variable in two function without having them in the global space.

Comment: thank you both for your input, i have changed my code a little, lets say i just wanted to pull out test var, the first function has a few vars set in it

Comment: that 2nd one does not makes sense to me i need the two functions totally seperate

Comment: @sluap: It might not fit your needs in that very case. However, it is a way to have a variable shared between two functions without exposing it to the global space.

Comment: @Tim, thank you ill have a read up on that when i have a little time